# Are webapps working in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: 14.04, unity, updates, 14.10, webapps

At the moment I am still using 14.04 the LTS version. 
Anybody using 14.10, has there been a fix on webapps ? Do they work or still get a blank screen?

Comment: Bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-webapps-googlecalendar/+bug/1395299

Answer (score 1):

Webapps do work in 14.04 LTS

If they don't work for you, then you most likely have some missing packages.

Comment: I know they work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, my question is if they work in 14.10, because webapps are a major reason stopping me from upgrading.

Comment: oh sure. That works in 14.10 as well. I use the google and fb ones and I didn’t have to do anything to get them working after upgrading to 14.10. They just did.

Comment: in mine they dont work. will try again and see today.

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu in gnome-boxes, nope they don't work again. If you don't mind what are your system specs? Could be something specific about my system the reason they don't work. And one question, do you use Ubuntu's web apps or those from Chromium?

Comment: ah I didnt realize that you are running Gnome. I have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: No Matv you missread. I wasn't running Gnome I was running Unity, gnome-boxes is a virtualbox software like oracle virtualbox.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 14.10 in a gnome-boxes (a kind of virtualbox) in order to test it. Do you know what virtualbox and gnome-boxes is?

Comment: actually no i didn't Gnome-box. Do now though. sorry. But yes I do know Oracle Virtual-box. Use it a lot. In that case it shouldn't make any difference whether you run Unity virtual or physically

Comment: Can you post the output of: apt-cache search unity-webapps